# BitTorrent Sync resets Device Name on restart

Tags: linux, ubuntu, synchronization, bittorrent-sync

Ubuntu 14.04 LTS BitTorrent Sync version 1.3.106 server version

Each time I reset the computer the Device Name is reset to the BitTorrent Sync default generated name (I believe the default is "[Computer name] - Default Instance"). I use the web interface to set the Device Name.

I have looked at changing the config file manually, but it warns that it is overwritten every restart.

How can I set the Device Name in a way that the name will be saved, and/or how does one fix the web interface so that the Device Name is saved?

Comment: Can you check the user that BitTorrent Sync is running as? It may not have access to change it's own configuration.

Comment: The user BitTorrent Sync is running as is btsync.

Comment: Does ls -l display that user for all of your configuration files? If not, you may need to use chown to change that. Or at least use chmod to give bysync access.

Comment: btsync does not have permission, but changing that and restarting the service does not fix the problem. 

I checked the configuration files [/etc/btsync/*] btsync did not have permission on some of them to write. debconf-default (the btsync instance the system tells me is running when I run `service btsync restart`) was 400 and owned by root. I changed it to 600. I changed ownership of the samples folder to btsync recursively and checked for at least 600 permissions on each of them. @Duckbrain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the web interface to try to name the instance, use the conf files.

Make a copy of the default conf file, and set options in there

```
cp /etc/btsync/debconf-default.conf /etc/btsync/[prefered conf name].conf
```

After setting the options you would like in `/etc/btsync/[prefered conf name].conf` make sure the user and or group that btsync runs as has at least read access. There are many ways to do this; I made the group of the conf file my btsync daemon group and turned on group read write access

```
chgrp btsync /etc/btsync/[prefered conf name].conf
chmod 060 /etc/btsync/[prefered conf name].conf
```

I only wanted 1 instance of btsync running, my new `/etc/btsync/[prefered conf name].conf` based one. You must edit `/etc/default/btsync` and add a line defining the one conf to run. The default is all conf in `/etc/btsync` (this may or may not include the defaults). Add this line to the file.

```
AUTOSTART="[prefered conf name]"
```

Restart the `btsync` service for the changes to take effect.

```
service btsync restart
```

Your instance of BitTorrent Sync may not be running as `btsync`. `btsync` is the default, but it is whatever you set it to at install. If you do not remember what it is it is in `/etc/btsync/debconf-default.conf`

```
DAEMON_UID=
```

is the user and

```
DAEMON_GID=
```

is the group

Answer based on info from [this site](http://blog.bittorrent.com/2013/09/17/sync-hacks-how-to-set-up-bittorrent-sync-on-ubuntu-server-13-04/).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the command line version of BitTorrent sync, you can try using the desktop gui version. Although it's not by resio, it works quite reliably for me.

Search for Bittorent sync desktop by Yeasoft and you should find it.